# How to set/change error pages for Force.com domain?

Tags: force.com-sites

We have a Force.com domain say my-domain.force.com and several sites there. I know that you can set error pages for each of those sites for example you can display your own page when someone will try to access my-domain.force.com/mysite/[unexisting page].

But can you somehow set or change error page for your Force.com domain which will be displayed when you try to access my-domain.force.com/[unexisting site]? It is strange that I can`t find the page that is currently displayed in this situation in my org. It shows page that one of our sites is under construction but we do not have such a page now.

Thanks!

Comment: I think it defaults to the FileNotFound Visualforce Page, I'm just messing around with one of my sites to confirm.

Comment: Hi Girbot, I\`ve checked this one but changing that page does not change what you actually see so I think it is not that page.

Comment: Salesforce support told that you can`t set it at domain level.

Comment: Can you please use the [contact us](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/contact) link to request this account be merged with [your other account](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/22421/oles-malkov)?

Answer (score 0):

See [Assigning Force.com Site Error Pages](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sites_error_pages.htm&language=th) in Help. You can upload pages to static resources to do what you're asking about. It sounds like you're asking about one of these three pages:

- **Maintenance Page**—The page users see when your site is down for maintenance.
- **Service Not Available Page**—The page users see when Salesforce servers are unavailable. This custom page is rendered from a static resource that you choose. The static resource is uploaded to the cache server when assigned as the Service Not Available page, and when updated after assignment. The custom page is shown for HTTP requests only; caching is not used for HTTPS. Not available for Developer Edition or sandbox organizations.
- **Page Not Found Page**—The page users see when trying to access a page that cannot be found. You can use the action attribute on an  component to redirect the Page Not Found error page. Using this kind of redirect on any other error pages will redirect users to the Maintenance page.

Comment: Hi crmprogdev, thanks for your reply but it is not actually what I\`m asking about. All that is possible for a Force.com SITE but I\`m asking for DOMAIN. In the link you\`ve posted I see step 2 "Click the name of the site you want to modify." But I`m trying to find error page that is domain-wide, I know how to set pages for a certain site. I need to find error page such as [your domain]/[unexisting page/site] not [your domain]/[your site]/[unexisting page].

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. You need to do that with your Domain Host. The page you're seeing is likely coming from your Domain Host since it's at the root of the link someone is trying to find. Normally a Domain Host will allow you to set up those kinds of pages and customize them. Those won't be served by salesforce, but instead by the Domain Host.

Answer (score 0):

There are two solutions for it:

1. Create Custom Visualforce Page and override existing error pages setting using our VF page.

- Go to Setup > Sites and Domains > Sites > Select your community by clicking the community name.
- Go to Error Page section > Click Page Page Assignment button and assign your custom VF Error page to a different Error Condition.

3. Edit existing Visualforce error pages

- CommunitiesLogin (Authorization Required Page)
- BandwidthExceeded  (Limit Exceeded Page)
- InMaintenance (Maintenance Page)
- FileNotFound  (Page Not Found Page)
- Exception (Generic Error Page)

More details you can find here: https://salesforceprofs.com/custom-community-error-page/